# Include in-text numeric values during sentiment anaylsis

Tags: machine-learning, keras, sentiment-analysis

I am working on sentiment analysis-like problem, Supposedly the text contains numbers which will make difference in categorization, for example:

```
I rate this product with 5 stars --> like
this product is 10x times worse --> hate
this product is 1x times worse --> don't like
```

How can these numbers be interpreted to affect the result, noting that, the text is free and no standards are used.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that you want to encode the sentences using the bag-of-words approach. Then, encoding each number to a separate index in unfeasible since there are infinitely many numbers. What I would do, is have `n` (`n` will probably be equal to the number of classes in your dates) indexes allocated for numbers where I would encode all numbers from the dataset. Then, where each number is going to end up will depend on a threshold. You can infer these thresholds from the training data. For example, all numbers bigger than `5` to a certain index, all numbers bigger than `10` to a different one and so on and so forth.